# Any way to ensure frisby.js test API calls go in sequential order?

Tags: rest, testing, jasmine, frisby.js

I'm trying a simple sequence of tests on an API:

1. Create a user resource with a `POST`
2. Request the user resource with a `GET`
3. Delete the user resource with a `DELETE`

I've a single frisby test spec file `mytest_spec.js`.  I've broken the test into 3 discrete steps, each with their own `toss()` like:

```
    f1 = frisby.create("Create");
    f1.post(post_url, {user_id: 1});
    f1.expectStatus(201);
    f1.toss();

    // stuff...

    f2 = frisby.create("Get");
    f2.get(get_url);
    f2.expectStatus(200);
    f2.toss();

    //Stuff...

    f3 = frisby.create("delete");
    f3.get(delete_url);
    f3.expectStatus(200);
    f3.toss();
```

Pretty basic stuff, right.  However, there is no guarantee they'll execute in order as far as I can tell as they're asynchronous, so I might get a 404 on test 2 or 3 if the user doesn't exist by the time they run.

Does anyone know the correct way to create sequential tests in Frisby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, *Frisby.js* is asynchronous. There are several approaches to force it to run more synchronously. The easiest but not the cleanest one is to use `.after(() -> ...` you can find more about `after()` in *Fisby.js* [docs](http://frisbyjs.com/docs/api/).

Comment: Yes, chaining non-trivial flows together with `after` gets messy, quick.  Are there other options to force pre-work for a test to get done first (stuff you don't really need to test, but need to setup for the test)?  This would make the chain of `After()` less lenghty.

Comment: Yes, in case of setup for the test - Let's say you have `scenario_spec.coffee` that requires account registration before executing. Then you can prepare file `env.coffee` and there provide your registration. Finally initialise `env     = require "./env"` at the beginning of `scenario_spec.coffee`, then you are sure that setup (registration) will be executed before your case.